# Break down java object of array which includes mixed types

Tags: java, arrays, object

I got an

```
Object obj
```

which includes an Array of mixed Types. For example,

```
System.out.println(obj.toString); //prints [4.3,3,size]
```

I need to access the "4.3" as `double`, the "3" as `int` and the "size" as `String`.

This is supposed to work:

```
 if (FirstElementOfobj instanceof String){
    System.out.println("String! "+ FirstElementOfobj+" works");
 } else if (FirstElementOfobj instanceof Integer) {
    System.out.println("Int! Adding 2 "+ FirstElementOfobj+2);
 } else if (FirstElementOfobj instanceof Double) {
    System.out.println("Double! Adding 3.0"+ FirstElementOfobj+3.0);
 }
```

But it doesn't because

```
System.out.println(obj.getClass()); // prints class java.util.ArrayList
```

So I think I need to break down the object in a way... I thought, if it's an `ArrayList`, shouldn't there be something like `obj[0]` to access the first element?

Edit:

the solution for my problem was

```
double myDouble = (double) ((ArrayList) obj).get(0);
```

Comment: You asked an answer.

Comment: To access your ArrayList by index (obj[0]) you first have to cast it ((ArrayList)obj)[0]

Comment: well, i cant use obj[0] because it says The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to Object.

Comment: Yes, this is why you have to explicitly cast it with ((ArrayList)obj)[0]

Comment: @Phillipe you can't do that with a cast either. You have to use the `List.get(int)` method: `((ArrayList) obj).get(0)`.

Comment: @Clashsoft your answer worked, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `obj` contains a `List` instance, cast it to `List` :

```
if (obj instance of List) {
    List list = (List) obj;
    for (Object o : list) {
        if (o instanceof Whatever) {
            Whatever w = (Whatever) o;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Please try this code ,
 I have create an Arraylist with different object types
 and print the result    you want you need to cast to Object to get 
 each object type inside the array list  


public static void main (String args[])
{

List myList = new ArrayList();

myList.add("StringValue");
myList.add(3.5);
myList.add(3);

for(int i = 0 ; i < myList.size();i++){


System.out.println((Object)myList.get(i).getClass());


}

} 


and there is the output 

class java.lang.String
class java.lang.Double
class java.lang.Integer
```